# Configure connection to 2nd monitor on dual boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub, peripherals

I have my laptop "docked" (meaning, the lid is closed, so the laptop's monitor and keyboard are inaccessible) in a stand and am currently using 2 monitors and an external keyboard.
Would I be able to configure grub such that:

It outputs to one of the two monitors and accepts input from the external keyboard **IF and only IF my laptop's lid is closed and both peripherals (monitor+keyboard) are plugged in**?

Thank you :)

Comment: Does it need to be "if and only if"? It maybe easier to accept input from both internal and external keyboard and to show output on both internal and external screen.

Comment: Hey, that would be okay too. Any idea how I can do that? :)